# finding total values for each month in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dataset

I need to find the total number of "wentto" trips for each month of the year . Assume all the months of 2010 are represented in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as tt,
       count(*) filter (where event = 'wentto')
from t
where date >= '2010-01-01' and date < '2011-01-01'
group by tt
order by tt;
```